# Redis count number of keys where value list is included in an argument list

Tags: redis, count

I have a list of around 2M IDS representing people. Each ID is linked to a list of URLS visited.
I have a list of banned URLS. I would like to know how many people have only visited banned sites. I would like to compute this info in less than 3 seconds.
My idea is this one:

- Get my data into redis: for each person, key would be its ID, value would be the list of URLS he visited.
- When I need the number of people who visited only a list I have of banned URLS (let's call it x) : compute the number of keys where the associated list is included into the x list.

Does redis match my use-case? Is there a better way to represent my data into redis ? Is the time constraint (3 seconds) is achievable?

Comment: Do you mean a user that visited at least one allowed URL shouldn't be included in the result?

Comment: It depends on how many people check at the same time and your H/W. Please clarify more detail of the use case.